# Is it possible to emulate template<auto X>?

Tags: c++, templates, type-inference

Is it somehow possible? I want that to enable compile-time passing of arguments. Suppose it's only for user convenience, as one could always type out the real type with `template<class T, T X>`, but for some types, i.e. pointer-to-member-functions, it's pretty tedious, even with `decltype` as a shortcut. Consider the following code:

```
struct Foo{
  template<class T, T X>
  void bar(){
    // do something with X, compile-time passed
  }
};

struct Baz{
  void bang(){
  }
};

int main(){
  Foo f;
  f.bar<int,5>();
  f.bar<decltype(&Baz::bang),&Baz::bang>();
}
```

Would it be somehow possible to convert it to the following?

```
struct Foo{
  template<auto X>
  void bar(){
    // do something with X, compile-time passed
  }
};

struct Baz{
  void bang(){
  }
};

int main(){
  Foo f;
  f.bar<5>();
  f.bar<&Baz::bang>();
}
```

Comment: @GMan: Updated, hope it makes more sense now. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After your update: no. There is no such functionality in C++. The closest is macros:

```
#define AUTO_ARG(x) decltype(x), x

f.bar<AUTO_ARG(5)>();
f.bar<AUTO_ARG(&Baz::bang)>();
```

---

Sounds like you want a generator:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo(const T&) {} // do whatever
};

template <typename T>
foo<T> make_foo(const T& x)
{
    return foo<T>(x);
}
```

Now instead of spelling out:

```
foo<int>(5);
```

You can do:

```
make_foo(5);
```

To deduce the argument.

Comment: This is even more useful in C++0x, where you can use `auto my_foo(make_foo(5));` without ever having to name the type `foo<int>` in entirety.

Comment: if passing the argument to a function would have been a concern then asker could have directly used `f.bar(5);` and declare the method simply as `template<typename T>void bar(T &X);`. What is the use of your `make_foo()` ?

Comment: @iammilind: It was for an old guess to his question, before he clarified.

Comment: @iamm: template argument deduction only works with functions, not classes.

Comment: Why isn't this possible, all the information is available to the compiler, it seems like a very arbitrary limitation?

Comment: @Jonathan. Could be as simple as nobody having proposed it yet.

Comment: @GManNickG, I mean it's the sort of thing that should have worked by default, it's as if someone went out of their way to specify it won't work.

Comment: @Jonathan.: I don't think many things in the language work by default, let alone `auto` as expanding to two separate template parameters.

Answer (score 7):

It was added in C++17
Now you can write

```
template<auto n> struct B { /* ... */ };
B<5> b1;   // OK: non-type template parameter type is int
B<'a'> b2; // OK: non-type template parameter type is char
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters, point 4 of **Non-type template parameter** section

Answer (score 0):

It's NOT possible. The only way to achieve is to **pass argument into the function**:

```
struct Foo{
  template<class T> void bar(T& X) {}
};
```

And then call the function as,

```
f.bar(5);
f.bar(&Baz::bang);
```