# Simplification of Template Class Specification

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I am very interested in the possibilities of template classes. Now, I am wondering how I can achieve following:

```
    Const<5>::getValue();
```

At the moment I can do this:

```
    Const<int, 5>::getValue());
```

And that's the implementation of the class:

```
    template <typename T, T value>
    class Const {
    public:
        typedef T Type;

        static T getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    };
```

I know this is just a very silly example, but once I can do that I could simplify following line:

```
    Getter<int, TestClass, &TestClass::get> getter;
```

to just:

```
    Getter<&TestClass::get> getter;
```

That would be TestClass :

```
    class TestClass {
    private:
        int _value;
    public:
        int get() {
            return _value;
        }
    };
```

Thanks for your help!

[EDIT-1]

In regards to J.N. yes, C++11 would be fine.

In regards to Xeo, I tried to use `#define AUTO_ARG(x) decltype(x), x` but that doesn't work within TestClass.

[EDIT-2]

In regards to KennyTM, when I declare the `Getter<...> g` within TestClass it doesn’t work with `Getter<AUTO_ARG(&TestClass::get)>` it only works with `Getter<int (TestClass::*)() const, &TestClass::get>`.

Now I am wondering if this is just a bug in Visual Studio???

Comment: Sorry for my first comment. Are you using C++11 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to emulate template<auto X>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628121/is-it-possible-to-emulate-templateauto-x)

Comment: And once you have `getter` defined, how do you intend on using it?

Comment: Did you look at Boost.MPL? They have a integral_c class that does pretty  much what your class Const does. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/integral-c.html

Answer (score 2):

You could still use `AUTO_ARG(x)` as given by [@Xeo's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628121/is-it-possible-to-emulate-templateauto-x). If you need to get the return type or the class type, just use pattern matching (i.e. template specialization):

```
template <typename T, T mem_fun_ptr>
struct Getter;

template <typename R, typename C, typename... A, R (C::*mem_fun_ptr)(A...) const>
struct Getter<R (C::*)(A...) const, mem_fun_ptr>
{
    typedef R return_type;
    typedef C class_type;
};
```

```
#define AUTO_ARG(x) decltype(x),(x)

class TestClass {
private:
    int _value;
public:
    int get() const {
        return _value;
    }
};

Getter<AUTO_ARG(&TestClass::get)> g;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but unfortunately it doesn't work when the Getter g is declared as a member of TestClass. Please have a look at [EDIT-2].

Comment: @user667967. You just add another specialization for the non-const version, i.e. `struct Getter<R(C::*)(A...), mem_fun_ptr>` and so on. In idiomatic C++ your **getter** should be const anyway.

Comment: Please have a close look to my [EDIT-2]. I still use the const version and I don’t think that is the problem. When I move `Getter<AUTO_ARG(&TestClass::get)> g;` to TestClass as a public member, I get the error message that a compile-time constant expression is expected. But when I replace `decltype(x)` with the correct type, then it works. I think that `decltype(x)` doesn’t work properly. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @user667967: Try to replace the specialization with `template <typename R, typename C, R (C::*mem_fun_ptr)() const>
struct Getter<R (C::*)() const, mem_fun_ptr>`. MSVC doesn't handle variadic templates properly.

Comment: I have finally found the solution! The problem was that `decltype()` didn’t properly work in my Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express version. After I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 11 Beta everything was fine. In regards to KennyTM, I didn’t use variadic templates but your complaint about the compiler I was using led me to the right thought. Thank you for your help!