# Using template argument as template argument type

Tags: c++, templates, template-function

I seem to be unable to use multiple layers of templates in the following manner,

```
template <typename T>
template <T value>
void printValueAsInteger()
{
    printf("value as integer is %i\n", (int) value);
}
```

so that it could be called as:

```
printValueAsInteger<123>();
```

It results in the following error message: `too many template-parameter-lists`.

It works if I use `template <typename T, T value>` with `printValueAsInteger<int, 123>()`, but that requires me to explicitly specify the type. How can I make it so that `printValueAsInteger<123>()` prints `value as integer is 123`?

**edit:**

I'll be more specific in what I need this for. My goal is to pass a member function as a function pointer, and I thought of wrapping it using templates:

```
template <typename T>
template <T* instance, void (T::*method)()>
void wrappedMethod()
{
    (instance->*method)();
}
void callFunction(void (*function)())
{
    (*function)();
}
```

and then pass it like this:

```
Base *instance = new Derived;
callFunction(&wrappedFunction<instance, Base::method>);
```

**edit:**

Err, I just realised that I probably shouldn't (and can't) use a runtime-defined variable as a template argument. I'm now trying to work around it using a class instantiated with the otherwise template arguments and creating a template function which uses that class. Or something like that. Nope, doesn't work.

Note that I cannot change the signature of callFunction, as it's part of a third party API.

**At last!**

I put the following in a header,

```
class Callable
{
public:
    virtual ~Callable() { }
    virtual void call() { }
};

typedef void (*functionPtr)();
extern unsigned nextMethodId;
extern functionPtr wrappedMethods[];
extern Callable *boundMethods[];

template <unsigned I>
class MethodWrapper
{
public:
    static void function();
};

template <typename T>
class Method : public Callable
{
public:
    Method(T* instance, void (T::*method)());
    virtual void call();
private:
    T* instance;
    void (T::*method)();
};

template <typename T>
Method<T>::Method(T* instance, void (T::*method)())
    : instance(instance), method(method) {
}

template <typename T>
void Method<T>::call()
{
    if (instance && method)
        (instance->*method)();
}

template <typename T>
static functionPtr bindMethod(T* instance, void (T::*method)())
{
    boundMethods[nextMethodId] = new Method<T>(instance, method);
    return (void (*)()) wrappedMethods[nextMethodId++];
}
```

and this in a source file:

```
#include "<insert header name here>.h"

unsigned nextMethodId = 0;
functionPtr wrappedMethods[] = {
    &MethodWrapper<0>::function,
    &MethodWrapper<1>::function,
    &MethodWrapper<2>::function
};
Callable *boundMethods[sizeof(wrappedMethods) / sizeof(functionPtr)];

template <unsigned I>
void MethodWrapper<I>::function()
{
    boundMethods[I]->call();
}
```

and I could use it like this:

```
Base *instance = new Derived;
void (*function)() = bindMethod(instance, &Base::method);
callFunction(function);
```

It successfully calls the derived instance's version of the method. Sadly, the amount of methods you are allowed to bind is fixed (three in this example), but it's easily extendable.

Comment: Sorry, not possible unless you fix the type of the non-type template parameter. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5628121/500104).

Comment: Why don't you use std::bind or boost::bind simply?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis Because I am unaware of the many benefits of using std or boost.

Answer (score 1):

A simple transform is having the *runtime* value be an argument to the constructor of a functor that holds the instance pointer and the pointer to member function. The syntax at the place of use will change from:

```
Base *instance = new Derived;
callFunction(&wrappedFunction<instance, Base::method>);
```

To:

```
callFunction( WrappedFunction<Base,&Base::method>( instance ) );
```

The implementation of the `WrappedFunction` type is actually simple, so I leave it as an exercise. Note that a major change in this approach is that the argument to `callFunction` becomes a *functor*, and not a function pointer.

In C++11 (or with boost) the simplest way would be not coding anything and just use the available resources. Change the signature of `callFunction` to:

```
void callFunction( function<void ()> f );
```

And use `bind` to place the call:

```
callFunction( bind( &Base::method, instance ) );
```

Comment: The problem is that the OP says that `callFunction` is part of an API from a third party, so it seems that the signature of `callFunction` cannot be changed.

Comment: The argument of `callFunction` does not become a functor; pointers to members are not functors (they're not compatible with the `f(a0, a1, ..., aN)` syntax).

Comment: @LucDanton: I should have been more clear: *with this change in design, `callFunction` would be changed to receive a functor instead of a pointer to member function*

Comment: @JesseGood: I did not realize that. If the signature of `callFunction` cannot be changed, then there is little that can be done in the sense that you cannot use a member function (which requires state) as a function that holds no state. There is always the possibility of *global state* (i.e. create a free function that will use a global object), but that is not a solution in the general term.

Answer (score 0):

For your first example, you can specify `int` as the type of template parameter:

```
template <int I>
void printValueAsInteger()
{
    printf("value as integer is %i\n", I);
}
```

For your edit, you cannot use runtime-defined variables as you have already mentioned because templates are used at compile-time. Using `std::bind` and `std::function` would make it simple:

```
void callFunction(std::function<void()> f)
{
    f();
}

Base *instance = new Derived;
callFunction(std::bind(&Base::method, instance));
```

**After Comment**

The only way I can think of is to make your member function `static`:

```
callFunction(&Base::method); // Okay if the method is declared static
```

Or use a global wrapper function with a global instance:

```
Base *instance = new Derived; // Global
void wrapperFunction()
{
    instance->method();
}

callFunction(wrapperFunction);
```

Comment: I need the callFunction to use a pointer, as it is part of an API for a library from a third party. std::function probably won't do, unless it can be converted to a function pointer, which I doubt.

Comment: @RpFeltz: That makes it a lot harder. The only way I can think of is to make your member function `static`.

Comment: Actually, perhaps I could put the information about the method in an externally linked array, and use the address of that as template argument... I'll try it.

Comment: @RPFeltz: I don't know why I didn't think of it before, but you could use a global wrapper and global instance.

Comment: That was the initial plan, but I was wondering if there was a less boring way than repeating this for thirty-or-so methods.

Comment: @RPFeltz: My only suggestion would be to ask another question and specify what API you are using and be specific about what you want to do. That way, someone may have a good solution to your problem.

Comment: It's pretty much my own fault. I was playing around with glut and thought "I'm bored. Oh, I know! Let's organise the callbacks." Then I put everything in classes and made them redirect events to more specific functions, and then I found out that virtual methods don't quite act the way I thought they did.