# Trying to use a template non-type parameter with an unknown type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, traits, decltype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to emulate template<auto X>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628121/is-it-possible-to-emulate-templateauto-x)

Consider the following working code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct Traits {};

template<typename T, typename A>
struct Traits<void(T::*)(A)>
{
   typedef T Class;
   typedef A Arg;
};

template<typename T, typename U, void(T::*MemFun)(U)>
void Builder()
{
   std::cout <<  typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout <<  typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout <<  typeid(MemFun).name() << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, T arg>
void Builder()
{
   return Builder<Traits<T>::Class,Traits<T>::Arg,arg>();
}

class Class
{
public:
   void foo(int) { }
};

int main()
{
   Builder<decltype(&Class::foo), &Class::foo>();
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this to get the same result, without using a macro.

```
int main()
{
   Builder<&Class::foo>();
}
```

I can't seem to create a template that takes the pointer to member and deduces the type.  Any thoughts?  The pointer to member must be used as a template argument as opposed to a function parameter because it's used to create a template function (not shown).

Comment: Can't you do `template <typename T> void Builder(T)` and `Builder(&Class::foo)`?

Answer (score 4):

Cannot be done. To have a non-type template argument you must provide the type. So either you limit your Builder to only one particular type or else you need an extra argument (first in the list) that is the type of second argument. Now, if you are willing not to use the member pointer as a constexpr... that is simple.

```
template <typename T, typename M>
struct Builder {
   M T::*ptr;
   Builder( M T::*ptr ) : ptr(ptr) {}
};
template <typename T, typename M>
Builder<T,M> createBuilder( M T::*ptr ) {
   return Builder<T,M>(ptr);
}
int main() {
   auto bld = createBuilder( &Class::member );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have spent some time trying to do a similar thing myself.

I don't think it is possible without using the name of the function `Class::foo` twice. My reasoning is as follows:

- to get the type of `foo` we must either use `decltype` or give `foo` as an argument to a template function
- in any of the above, the constexpr-ness of `foo` (allowing it to be used as a template argument) is lost
- moreover, we cannot "duplicate" `foo` inside a template class or function, as it would face the same problem as above
- conclusion: we have to type `foo` twice at the outer scope

It seems one cannot get away without "dirty" macro tricks, even in C++11...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to do type deduction for the type of non-type template parameters. A macro is really the only option here.