# How to get member function's quoting type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to emulate template<auto X>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628121/is-it-possible-to-emulate-templateauto-x)

Following C++ code worked in vc2010

```
template<class T, DWORD (T::*memFnPtr)() >
static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProcAdapter( __in LPVOID lpParameter )
{
    T* pThis = reinterpret_cast<T*>(lpParameter);
    return (pThis->*memFnPtr)();
}

class FooClass
{
public:

    DWORD ThreadProcFoo()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

void fooUse()
{
    FooClass foo;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProcAdapter<FooClass, &FooClass::ThreadProcFoo>, &foo, 0, NULL);
}
```

Question: Can we make ThreadProcAdapter<> template to use only one parameter?? If so, it will be relatively easy for client to use our adapter.

```
template<class T>
static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProcAdapter2( __in LPVOID lpParameter )
{
    //typedef 
    //theClass* pThis = reinterpret_cast<theClass*>(lpParameter);
    //return (pThis->*memFnPtr)();
    return NULL;
}

void fooUse2()
{
    FooClass foo;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProcAdapter2<&FooClass::ThreadProcFoo>, &foo, 0, NULL);
}
```

Specifically:
If we have a member function pointer

```
&FooClass::ThreadProcFoo
```

can we cacluate out its class's type

```
FooClass
```