# Is there any way to derive the object type from a member pointer type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

Is it possible to write a C++ template `owner_of<...>` such that given this code:

```
struct X { int y; }
```

`owner_of<&X::y>::type` is `X`?

Comment: Yes, you can partially specialize owner_of<T X::*>.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I'm struggling to construct the syntax - care to show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *almost* do that (or at least I could not find a better solution so far):

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct owner_of { };

template<typename T, typename C>
struct owner_of<T (C::*)>
{
    typedef C type;
};

struct X
{
    int x;
};

int main(void)
{
    typedef owner_of<decltype(&X::x)>::type should_be_X;
    static_assert(is_same<should_be_X, X>::value, "Error" );
}
```

If you mind the use of `decltype`, maybe a macro could do:

```
#define OWNER_OF(p) owner_of<decltype( p )>::type

int main(void)
{
    typedef OWNER_OF(&X::x) should_be_X;
    static_assert(is_same<should_be_X, X>::value, "Error" );
}
```

An alternative solution based on `decltype:`

```
template<typename T, typename C>
auto owner(T (C::*p)) -> typename owner_of<decltype(p)>::type { }

int main(void)
{
    typedef decltype(owner(&X::x)) should_be_X;
    static_assert(is_same<should_be_X, X>::value, "Error" );
}
```

Comment: Unfornately I trimmed down my example too much. What I'm actually looking for is a way to reduce `some_class<X, &X::x>` to `some_class<&X::x>`

Comment: @Eric: Then I'm afraid you won't be able to do that. There is no equivalent of "typename" for literals. The same way as "typename" accepts any class type, you would need a "literal" that accepts any literal, and which you would then specialize. But no such a thing exists unfortunately.

Comment: @Eric: As Andy says, nobody found a way to do that yet. The best you can do is `some_class<decltype(&X::x), &X::x>` and hide that behind a macro. :/ See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5628121/500104).

Comment: @AndyProwl: I'll take your word for it. This was still helpful, so I've accepted it - thanks.