# Better syntax to bind function to type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to bind functions into types - consider the following test program:

```
#include <utility>

template <class Ret, class Arg>
struct func {
    typedef Ret (&ref)(Arg);
    template <ref Fn>
    struct bind {
        template <class NewArg>
        Ret operator()(NewArg&& arg) {
            return Fn(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
        }
    };
};

int foo(int i) {
    return i;
}

typedef func<int, int>::bind<foo> Foo;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Foo foo_obj;
    return foo_obj(argc);
}
```

This works, but I personally find `func<int, int>::bind<foo>` ugly, and it's also redundant - but I can't seem to do `func::bind<foo>` and have Ret and Arg deduced from the template argument to bind (or the moral equivalent therof).  I would do something like this:

```
template <class Ret, class Arg>
constexpr auto bind_func(typename func<Ret, Arg>::ref f) -> typename func<Ret, Arg>::bind<f> {
    return {};
}
```

However, because f is not guaranteed to be a constant expression this cannot compile, as the compiler cannot know that f is a valid template argument.

Is there a way to accomplish this without constant redundancy?

Comment: May I ask, why can't you just use `std::bind`?

Comment: Because I need the type to be constexpr default constructable without losing context.  I don't need all of the features of bind, I just need to be able to wrap the function in a type.

Comment: [Relevant.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5628121/500104)

Comment: So a macro is the only way to do it non-verbosely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If macros are acceptable to you, here is a possible solution:

```
#include <utility>

template <class Ret, class Arg>
struct func {
    typedef Ret (&ref)(Arg);
    template <ref Fn>
    struct bind {
        template <class NewArg>
        Ret operator()(NewArg&& arg) {
            return Fn(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
        }
    };
};

template<typename T>
struct traits { };

template<typename R, typename A>
struct traits<R(A)>
{
    typedef R return_type;
    typedef A arg_type;
};

int foo(int i) {
    return i;
}

#define TYPE_WRAP(f) \
    func< \
        traits<decltype(f)>::return_type, \
        traits<decltype(f)>::arg_type \
        >::bind<f>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    TYPE_WRAP(foo) foo_obj;
    return foo_obj(argc);
}
```