# How to rewrite this to make it conforming to the C++ Standard

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

The following code snippet demonstrates what I would like to achieve, namely creating two template specializations (well, here it's a main template and a specialization), one which will be used for non-const member functions and one for const member functions:

```
// instantiate for non-const member functions
template <typename C, void(C::*F)()>
struct A {};

// instantiate for const member functions
template <typename C, void(C::*F)() const>
struct A<C const, F> {};

struct foo
{
    void bar() const {}
    typedef A<foo const, &foo::bar> bar_type;

    void baz() {}
    typedef A<foo, &foo::baz> baz_type;
};
```

While this code compiles fine using gcc 4.7, Intel 13.0 and MSVC 2012, it fails to compile using Clang 3.3 or Comeau 4.3.10.1. I trust Clang is actually right.

How to rewrite this code to make it standards conforming (i.e. compiling with Clang)?

Here is the compilation error:

```
test_6.cpp:22:26: error: non-type template argument of type 'void (foo::*)() const' cannot be converted to a value of type 'void (const foo::*)()'
    typedef A<foo const, &foo::bar> bar_type;
                         ^~~~~~~~~
test_6.cpp:7:33: note: template parameter is declared here
template <typename C, void (C::*F)()>
                                ^
```

Comment: Why not show us the compilation error? Why not provide version information?

Comment: *"it fails to compile"* ...with an error message?

Comment: I added the compiler versions and the Clang error message.

Comment: Your partial specialization doesn't match the primary template, so isn't a valid specialization. The second parameter of the partial specialization has a different type to the second parameter of the primary template.

Comment: Jonathan I know that. I want to know how to rewrite it :-P

Comment: that's odd, is `void (foo::*)() const` different from `void (const foo::*)()`? aren't both indicating that the implicit `this` parameter is `const`?

Comment: @StephenLin, a const member function is not the same as a non-const member function of a const type, so no

Comment: I believe you when you say those are different types, but Stephen's point is valid.  They shouldn't be different types, or at least the one should be implicitly convertible to the other.  Seems like a possible language defect.

Comment: @BenVoigt no, it makes sense, in one case the function is declared `const`, in the other case the function is declared non-`const` but the object happens to be `const`. you can always take a `T` and make it `const T` but that won't change the declaration of its member functions to be `const`: C++ `const` is not transitive like that

Comment: @StephenLin: "The function is declared non-`const` but the object happens to be `const`" is not a viable scenario.  For a `const` object, only `const` and `mutable` members exist (the others cannot be used).

Comment: @BenVoigt hmm...i'm not sure what you mean...only `const` member functions of `const` objects are callable (I'm not sure whether it technically means the non-`const` ones do not exist or not), but that does not change the signature of a function that was declared non-`const` and make it `const`. Even if "the function is declared non-`const` but the object happens to be `const`" is not a viable scenario for a callable member function, it is not equivalent to "the function is declared `const` but the object happens to be non-`const`". I grant that I might be missing something, though...

Comment: @StephenLin: The address of a non-`const` member has to be pointer-to-non-const-member-function of non-`const` type.  The address of a `const` member could be either pointer-to-`const`-member-function of non-`const` type or pointer-to-(implicitly `const`)-member-function of `const` type. There's nothing inconsistent about getting rid of the pointer-to-member vs pointer-to-const-member distinction, and just tracking the type of implicit `this`, as you originally suggested.

Comment: @BenVoigt ok, I think I see what you mean, it could work to collapse the distinction because there might be no practical situation in you care about the difference. apparently that's just not how the type system is designed. The new C++11 ref qualifiers (i.e. rvalue for `*this`) might make the situation more complicated though, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the member function type a template parameter then you can specialize the template for different member function types:

```
template <typename C, typename F, F>
struct A;  // undefined

template <typename C, void(C::*f)()>
struct A<C, void(C::*)(), f> {};

template <typename C, void(C::*f)() const>
struct A<C const, void(C::*)() const, f> {};

struct foo
{
    void bar() const {}
    typedef A<foo const, decltype(&foo::bar), &foo::bar> bar_type;

    void baz() {}
    typedef A<foo, decltype(&foo::baz), &foo::baz> baz_type;
};
```

Comment: The specialization doesn't take the original function type into account at all at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how (partial) specialization works. When you provide an argument in a specialization, it has to match the corresponding parameter's kind.

Your primary template has a *pointer-to-**non-const**-member-function* (PTNCMF) parameter, expecting a template argument of that kind. Your partial specialization, however, passes a *pointer-to-**const**-member-function* (PTCMF) as the argument, creating a mismatch. A PTCMF isn't convertible to a PTNCMF, so the partial specialization isn't valid.

So much for the problem, on to the solution. You need to seperate the *type* of the argument from the actual argument. One way would be the following, simply asserting that a `const` class type is only ever matched with a PTCMF.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class Fty>
struct is_ptcmf : std::false_type{};

template<class C, class R, class... Args>
struct is_ptcmf<R (C::*)(Args...) const> : std::true_type{};

template<class C, class Fty, Fty F>
struct A{
  static_assert(std::is_const<C>() == is_ptcmf<Fty>(), "Must pair const with const.");
};
```

[Live example.](https://ideone.com/xvgqNg)

Usage would then be `A<foo, decltype(&foo::bar), &foo::bar>`. If you think there is some redundancy, I agree, but [there is no nice way yet to get rid of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5628121/500104).

Comment: That does not answer my question. I already said Clang is right and this code is non-conforming.

Comment: @StephenLin: So far, it looked like he just wanted to make sure both are paired, however, if that's not exactly what he wanted, it's easy to create the specialization scenario out of it with a bit of `enable_if` magic.

Comment: @Xeo I deleted the comment because I thought I misread your code, but after I did apparently I realized I did not. Anyway, yeah, it's not a big deal, just wanted to point out that it looked like he wanted two different specializations; should be doable with SFINAE pretty easily though, though, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records, here is how I solved it:

```
template <typename F, F ptr>
struct A;  // undefined

template <typename C, void (C::*F)()>
struct A<void (C::*)(), F> {};

template <typename C, void (C::*F)() const>
struct A<void (C::*)() const, F> {};

struct foo
{
    void bar() const {}
    typedef A<decltype(&foo::bar), &foo::bar> bar_type;

    void baz() {}
    typedef A<decltype(&foo::baz), &foo::baz> baz_type;
};
```

Thanks everybody for your insights!