# Is it possible to extract type from a pointer template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to define a template which takes a single pointer parameter and extracts the type pointed to?

```
extern int three = 3;
typename examine<&three>::pointed_type // int
```

Comment: [`pointer_traits<T>::element_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628121

Answer (score 2):

There's already `std::remove_pointer<T>::type` in `<type_traits>` (C++11) that you can use.

Comment: That won't help in this case- I want to pass a pointer as the template parameter, rather than a type.

Comment: Use `decltype(&three)` instead then: `remove_pointer<decltype(&three)>::type`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would use partial specialization to achieve this, similar to the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct examine {
    typedef T pointed_type;
};

template<typename T>
struct examine<T*> {
    typedef T pointed_type;
};
```

To refer to your comment about usage of non-type template parameters, consider the following:

```
template<typename T, T* p>
struct foo { };

extern int three = 3;
foo<decltype(three), &three> bar;
```

As you can see, `foo` can indeed take a template parameter of `&x`, but to do so we first need to give it a `type` parameter (or restrict it to `int*`, which does not help at all). If this is not done, the name `T` is not that of any type when the template parameter `p` is defined.

There is no way at all to perform any kind of automatic deduction of `T`, since that would require the template arguments to be defined in the other order.

The closest you can get without using `decltype` is by defining a function template that gets a non-template argument that will cause the template type parameter to be deduced like so

```
template<typename T>
void deduce_argument_type(T const&)
{
    // here, the type T is (close to) that of your argument
}
deduce_argument_type(&three); // uses deduce_argument_type<int*>
```

Again, you cannot use this to get around the restriction on defining `T` before passing `&three`, since template parameter deduction only deduces any types to the right of those template parameters you passed.

Comment: This gives me an 'error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class T> struct examine'`.

Comment: You cannot use a value as a type. Thus putting `&three` in pointy brackets is wrong in any case. You either need to use C++11 `decltype` if you wish to do that, or use a function template and pass `&three` to it, so that its argument type is deduced to `int*`.

Comment: C++ allows [non-type template parameters.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fnon-type_template_parameters.htm)

Comment: Indeed it does, however there is no possibility of using that to deduce a type. This constraint is caused by syntax restrictions.