# Compile time interval checker

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compile-time

I can't find a compile-time interval checker so I have tried some approaches to develop an own where you should enter the value in question, the min value and the max value, so that the checker would return true if the value in question is between the two endpoints.

My first approach was just to be able to compare ints and it looked like this:

```
template<int Val, int LoEnd, int HiEnd>
struct is_in_interval : public std::integral_constant<bool, Val >= LoEnd && Val <= HiEnd>::type
{};
```

A call to the function would look like

```
bool inside = is_in_interval<3, 1, 10>::value;
```

and that seemed to work. 
I could even make it fail at compile time if the lower end was higher than the higher end:

```
template<int val, int LoEnd, int HiEnd>
struct is_in_interval : public std::integral_constant< typename std::enable_if<LoEnd <= HiEnd, bool>::type, val >= LoEnd && val <= HiEnd>::type
{};
```

To be able to compare any value I came up with this:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_in
{
    template<T val, T LoEnd, T HiEnd>
    struct closed_interval : public std::integral_constant< typename std::enable_if<LoEnd <= HiEnd, bool>::type, val >= LoEnd && val <= HiEnd>::type
    {};
};
```

Now, however, the calls became more obscure:

```
bool inside = is_in<int>::closed_interval<3,1,10>::value;
```

but I still had the ability to use enable_if and could even add more (to check for is_integral for example).

My question is if it somehow is possible to make that generalized version easier to call, probably by deducing the type (int) from the non-type (3,1,10) above?

On a sidenote I could use:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool isInInterval3(T val, T LoEnd, T HiEnd)
{
    return val >= LoEnd && val <= HiEnd;
}
```

but in that function I don't think I can use the `std::enable_if` type trait to assert that`LoEnd <= HiEnd`.

Comment: You can still use `isInInterval3` to make a compile-time check: `constexpr bool assert_isIn(T const val, T const min, T const max) { return val >= min && val <= max ? true : throw "out of range"; }` When using such a function in a context where a constant expression is required, instead of an exception, you'll get a compile-time error. But that's not very useful; I'd rather use `static_assert(isInInterval3(val, lo, hi), "!!");` with your current definition.

Comment: @dyp Neither SFINAE-friendly nor a nice and elegant way to finish it?

Comment: @Columbo As a basic building block, I think the OP's `isInterval3` is useful. You can build both SFINAE and hard error on top of that. As I said, I think my `assert_isIn` is not very useful.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5628121 there are a lot of these questions related to deducing the type of non-type template parameters / some kind of non-type parameter that accepts all types.

Comment: @Columbo Btw the OP's check with `enable_if` isn't SFINAE either (not in the immediate context since it's in the base clause), so it could be replaced with a `static_assert`. (Also, the check `lo < hi` does not need SFINAE IMHO, it's a logic/programming error if it fails.)

Comment: Clang's attribute [`enable_if`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#enable-if) can be used to enable compile-time SFINAE based on the argument values.

Comment: I tried to replace the body of your `constexpr` templated function with your `is_in` struct `value` field but gcc 4.9.1 doesn't seem to like that...

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/891ed2709dd24192    IsInterval3 work for enable_if just fine.

Comment: Why even forbid `LoEnd > HiEnd`? You could use that to make empty intervals.

Comment: @dyp Yes I'm leaning against to just use isInInterval3 as a compile time check.

Comment: @JayMiller Yes isInInterval3 works as a compile time check, but I ment that I don't know a way to test that inside isInterval3. I can't use a static_assert and I don't think I can use enable_if

Comment: @DanielKO Yeah i was thinking about that as well, or reorder to always get a correct interval.

Comment: You have to consider what the trade offs are; why would I write something complicated instead of just `LoEnd <= x && x <= HiEnd`? What are the chances of a sober programmer to mess up with the order in that statement?

Comment: @DanielKO Yeah I partially agree with you, but I rather pick up an error at compile time. However in this example it might not be needed, like you pointed out.

Comment: `constexpr bool isIn(int val, int min, int max) { return min > max ? throw "logic error" : val >= min && val <= max; }` will produce a compile-time error if `min > max` AND used in a context where a constant expression is required.

Comment: Why you don't use `static_assert(min <= value && value <= max);`? You will have compile time check and no boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify both 'typename T' and other parameters in one template:

```
template<typename T, T val, T LoEnd, T HiEnd>
struct is_in_interval : public std::integral_constant<
typename std::enable_if<LoEnd <= HiEnd, bool>::type, val >= LoEnd && val <= HiEnd>::type
{};
```

Then, you can define a macro `in_interval` with only val, LoEnd and HiEnd parameters which will call `is_in_interval` with first template parameter, for example, `decltype(val)`:

```
#define in_interval(val, LoEnd, HiEnd) (is_in_interval<decltype(val), val, LoEnd, HiEnd>::value)
```

And you can use it as follows:

```
cout << in_interval(3, 1, 10) << endl;
```

This all works on my VS2012